# Почему Collection.sort возвращает нули?

Tags: java, коллекции

Задание состоит в том, чтобы отсортировать объекты.
Необходимо создать список из двадцати объектов. КАждый объект - это комната со случайно заданными шириной и длиной.

Класс RoomComporator воплощает интерфейс Comporator. 
Я хочу отсортировать комнаты в соответствии с их площадями, используя следующую команду: Collection.sort( list, new RoomComparator())

Отсортированый список нужно вывести на консоль.
Вопрос в том, что я не понимаю как работает Collection.sort, когда в аргументе есть объект другого класса. Мой код возвращает нули.

Вот код для класса RoomComporator:

```
import java.util.Comparator;
public  class RoomComporator  implements Comparator<Room> {

public RoomComporator(){}


@Override
public int compare(Room r1, Room r2 ) {

return r1.square- r2.square;}

}
```

И код для главного класса Room:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Room {

int length;
int width;
int square;


public int getWidth(){
    return this.width;
}

public void setWidth(int width){
    this.width = width;
}

public int getLength(){
    return this.length;
}

public int setLength(int length){
    return this.length = length;
}
public Room(int l, int w) {
    this.length = l;
    setWidth(w);
}
void square(){
    int l, w;
    l = length;
    w = width;

    int s = w*l;
    System.out.println(s);

}

Room (int square){
    this.square=square;
}


void printRoom(){
System.out.println(length   + "   " +   width);
}

public static void main(String[] args){

List<Room> rooms = new LinkedList <Room>();
int numRooms = 20;
int maxLength = 9;
int maxWidth = 9;



for( int i = 0; i < numRooms; i++)
{
    int length =  1 + (int)(Math.random()*maxLength);
    int width = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*maxWidth);
    Room r = new Room(length, width);
    System.out.println("Room " + (i + 1));
    r.printRoom();

    r.square();
    rooms.add(r);

}


for( int i = 0; i < numRooms; i++){
    Collections.sort(rooms, new RoomComporator());
    System.out.println(rooms.get(i).square);}

}
}
```

Comment: А почему вы думаете что square будет отличным от нулл, если вы его не изменяете(Соответствующий конструктор вы не вызываете)?

Answer (score 1):

Вместо реализации компаратора реализуйте интерейфейс Comparable для Room

```
 public class Room implements Comparable {

    public int compareTo(Room room){

        return this.square - room.square;
```

http://metanit.com/java/tutorial/5.6.php

Answer (score 0):

Ваш класс `Room` должен реализовать интерфейс `Comparable`

```
List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
Comparator<MyObject> comparator = new Comparator<MyObject>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(MyObject left, MyObject right) {
        return left.getId() - right.getId(); 
    }
};

Collections.sort(list, comparator);
System.out.println(list);
```

Java 8 используя лямбда

```
List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
Collections.sort(list, (left, right) -> left.getId() - right.getId());
System.out.println(list);
```

Подробный пример...

```
import java.util.*;

class Dog implements Comparator<Dog>, Comparable<Dog> {
   private String name;
   private int age;
   Dog() {
   }

   Dog(String n, int a) {
      name = n;
      age = a;
   }

   public String getDogName() {
      return name;
   }

   public int getDogAge() {
      return age;
   }

   // Overriding the compareTo method
   public int compareTo(Dog d) {
      return (this.name).compareTo(d.name);
   }

   // Overriding the compare method to sort the age 
   public int compare(Dog d, Dog d1) {
      return d.age - d1.age;
   }
}

public class Example {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      // Takes a list o Dog objects
      List<Dog> list = new ArrayList<Dog>();

      list.add(new Dog("Shaggy", 3));
      list.add(new Dog("Lacy", 2));
      list.add(new Dog("Roger", 10));
      list.add(new Dog("Tommy", 4));
      list.add(new Dog("Tammy", 1));
      Collections.sort(list);   // Sorts the array list

      for(Dog a: list)   // printing the sorted list of names
         System.out.print(a.getDogName() + ", ");

      // Sorts the array list using comparator
      Collections.sort(list, new Dog());
      System.out.println(" ");

      for(Dog a: list)   // printing the sorted list of ages
         System.out.print(a.getDogName() +"  : "+ a.getDogAge() + ", ");
   }
}
```